# How to alter WinSCP script for recursively searching for text to print just a folder of the first match and exit

Tags: powershell, ftp, winscp, winscp-net

I want to be able to look for a text string in all folders on a remote FTP server. Once found, I need to know the name of the folder which contains the text document BUT **not** the name of the file.

How can I make changes to *"Action on match"* to make this script ([WinSCP Extension Search recursively for text in remote directory / Grep files over SFTP/FTP protocol](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library_example_recursive_search_text)) run silently (without displaying anything in the terminal) and once the match is found simply stop and display ONLY the name of the folder (containing the file with the text string)? Also is it possible to display the result in red? Here is the *"Action on match"* portion of the script (I tried to include the whole thing but cannot do it for some reason).

I can do this with the help of the latest WinSCP custom *Search for Text* button (please see .ps1 script below which makes this search function possible). However instead of just stopping upon match, the search goes on until the last folder. What is worse is that in order to find the result I need to scroll all the way back up and check every entry. Only one of them will have the name of my folder listed so that is a long procedure.

```
{
    # Action on match

    # Modify the code below if you want to do another task with
    # matching files, instead of grepping their contents

    Write-Host ("File {0} matches mask, searching contents..." -f $fileInfo.FullName)
    $tempPath = (Join-Path $env:temp $fileInfo.Name)
    # Download file to temporary directory
    $sourcePath = [WinSCP.RemotePath]::EscapeFileMask($fileInfo.FullName) 
    $transferResult = $session.GetFiles($sourcePath, $tempPath)
    # Did the download succeeded?
    if (!$transferResult.IsSuccess)
    {
        # Print error (but continue with other files)
        Write-Host $transferResult.Failures[0].Message
    }
    else
    {
        # Search and print lines containing "text".
        # Use -Pattern instead of -SimpleMatch for regex search
        $matchInfo = Select-String -Path $tempPath -SimpleMatch $text
        # Print the results
        foreach ($match in $matchInfo)
        {
            Write-Host ($fileInfo.FullName + ":" + $match.LineNumber + ":" + $match.Line)
        }
        # Delete temporary local copy
        Remove-Item $tempPath
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
{
    # Action on match

    # Modify the code below if you want to do another task with
    # matching files, instead of grepping their contents

    $tempPath = (Join-Path $env:temp $fileInfo.Name)
    # Download file to temporary directory
    $sourcePath = [WinSCP.RemotePath]::EscapeFileMask($fileInfo.FullName)
    $transferResult = $session.GetFiles($sourcePath, $tempPath)
    # Did the download succeeded?
    if (!$transferResult.IsSuccess)
    {
        # Print error (but continue with other files)
        Write-Host $transferResult.Failures[0].Message
    }
    else
    {
        # Use -Pattern instead of -SimpleMatch for regex search
        $matchInfo = Select-String -Path $tempPath -SimpleMatch $text
        Remove-Item $tempPath

        if ($matchInfo)
        { 
            # Print a path to the file's folder and exit
            Write-Host ($fileInfo.FullName -replace "/[^/]*$")
            exit
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you soooo much Martin for your super fast response, this is what I've been looking for! I've made some minor adjustments and it's working perfectly. Do you know of a way of automating the task - i.e. I can start WinSCP into the session easily with a batch but I have trawled through dozens of pages of WinSCP forum and cannot figure out how to automate the Search for Text button (in other words, the user clicks on the batch on his desktop and WinSCP starts up followed by the Search for Text window). This is a bit of luxury of course.. Once again thank you so much for your help.

Comment: Just now noticed that every time I do a search the terminal lists the folder name twice for some off reason.. although I know for a fact there's only one such folder. Well, no big deal I guess.

Comment: In the latest WinSCP 5.8.4, if you hold down Ctrl and Shift keys while clicking OK on the command options dialog, the command to run the search gets copied to the clipboard. The just paste the command to the batch file. Plus you need to call `set WINSCP_PATH=c:\program files (x86)\winscp\winscp.exe` before that.

Comment: Hello Martin, thank you for your suggestion but I've tried for a couple of days now and had no luck. When I copy the command to the clipboard I get the following:powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File "C:\
Program Files (x86)\WinSCP\Extensions\SearchText.WinSCPextension.ps1" -sessionUr
l "ftp://ingest:ingest@192.168.114.111/" -path "/content/" -text "" -wildcard "*
.xml" -pause -sessionLogPath "". I then make a batch with this command and get the following error:

Comment: Error: Exception setting "Path": "Cannot find path 'C:\Program Files (x86)\WinSC
P\Extensions\WinSCPnet.dll' because it does not exist."

Comment: If I start the same batch with your set WINSCP_PATH string I get the error:x86 : The term 'x86' is not recognised as a the name of a cmdlet, function, script file or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again. At line:1 char:48, -ExtensionPolicy Bypass -File C:\Porgram File. Do you know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Yes, just did a few more tests and exactly the same - for some reason the powershell.exe command of the batch looks for \winscp\winscp.exe\WinSCPnet.dll, which doesn't exist of course.

Comment: OK, it should have been `set WINSCP_PATH=c:\program files (x86)\winscp`

Comment: Yes, I tried it and many more combinations. Maybe it's because I'm on Sever 2008 R2. This is what I get
C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop>set WINSCP_PATH=c:\program files (x86)\winscp

C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop>powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File "C:\
Program Files (x86)\WinSCP\Extensions\SearchText.WinSCPextension.ps1" -sessionUr
l "ftp://ingest:ingest@192.168.111.111/" -path "/content/" -text "" -wildcard "*
.*" -pause -sessionLogPath ""
Error: Cannot bind argument to parameter 'Pattern' because it is an empty string
.
Press any key to exit...

Comment: In other words it does a terminal search, which is fine but then you have to edit the batch and enter a string between the "". I thought this was meant to start winscp gui and activate the Search for Text button.

Comment: Just remove the `-text ""` from the command-line to have PowerShell prompt you for the value on the start.

Comment: Completely misunderstood you at first and that's why I was going in circles. Got it now, everything's working perfectly. Thank so much for all your help, I would not get anywhere without it and the wonderful tool you created!

Comment: Sorry, I'm new to this, how do you do that? I can't find the button.

Comment: Yes, clicked on that and it turned green - I guess that's it?